# Changing Views in a "Single View Application"

Tags: objective-c, ios

Disclaimer: I am *very* new to iOS development. Please excuse the possible stupidity of the question :)

I started a "Single View Application" in XCode, and it now has an interface in a "storyboard", which is all hooked up to code and working great. Now, I realize that I need another view. What is the simplest way to do this (creating the other view now, and switching between them in code). I really don't care about animations.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT: Many thanks for all your help. I ended up creating a new project with no ARC or Storyboard and setting the minimum-version-thing to 4.0. Then I used Mats Stijlaart's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new view from a XIB do this:

- Make a UIViewController subclass. (.h + .m)
- Make a empty XIB.
- Make the UIViewController subclass the file owner of the XIB.
- Add a UIView.
- Ctr-drag from the file owner to the UIView to link the view property to the UIView.
- Make your view.

In your code.
I assume your currently having 1 controller class which is linked to a view that is shown on the screen.

In this controller you probably have an event which you want to couple to show a new view. Lets say myEvent.

```
- (IBAction) myEvent:(id)sender {
    ViewControllerSubClass *subClass = [[ViewControllerSubClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourXIB" bundle:nil];
    subClass.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    subClass.view.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
    [self.view.superview addSubview:subClass.view];

    //ARC
    instanceVarSubClass = subClass;

    //NO ARC
    self.instanceVarSubClass = subClass;
    [subClass release];
}
```

You should make a strong instance variable (ARC) or a property with the (retain) keyword.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use a NavigationController and another ViewController.

In your storyboard, select the ViewController that is present there. Then, click "Editor" in the menu and select, "Embed in" > NavigationController.

Second, create a new UIViewcontroller subclass Drag a UIViewController onto the storyboard. and set it's class in the Identity Inspector to the viewcontroller you just created.

Third, click the ctrl-key and drag from the first viewController to the one you just dragged onto the storyboard. A popup will apear. Click "Push". You have just created a segue. Congratulations :)

Click the segue ( the line between the ViewControllers) and give it a Identifier in the property-inspector.

Next, in your code, do this ([segue-identifier] is the identifier you just gave.):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"[segue-identifier]" sender:self];

....

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"[segue-identifier]"])
    {
        second *controller=[segue destinationViewController];
        //do stuff with the new controller here, for instance: delegation.
    }
}
```

That's it I think! Hope I didn't forget anything important ;)

Comment: You wouldn't need code to perform the segue since the storyboard would do it already, but I can't think of anything you've missed. Good answer and a sound alternative to mine - OP can now choose if they want navigation or modal views.

Comment: Sorry, retract the first part of my comment - you would need code to perform the segue if you'd just connected it from one view controller to the next. I thought you'd said to connect it from a button.

Answer (score 0):

In your project add a new UIViewController subclass.

In your storyboard, drag a new view controller into the storyboard next to your existing one. In the identity inspector set the custom class to your new view controller class.

Put a new button on the original view controller, then ctrl-drag from it to your new view controller. Select "modal" from the segue type pop-up.

At this point you will be able to run your app, press the new button and your new view controller's view will appear.

To switch back to the first view, you'll need another button in the new view controller that calls `dismissModalViewController:animated:`. The rest is up to you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty new to iOS development and have not had much experience with storyboarding but the apps I've done for clients have been fairly simple in their needs and because of that I wanted to be able to target iOS versions prior to 4.0.

If the case is similar for your app (that is you do not use any main features from iOS 4/5) then I'd recommend just sticking with using XIB files. ThomasM has given a lot more detailed answer than I could on using storyboards but with XIBs and NavigationControllers it's something as simple as:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```